# How to enable files and directory listing in Docker Apache Container

Tags: docker, apache, dockerfile, webserver, httpd.conf

I'm using the Apache httpd image to create a simple web server. I wanted to know how I can use it so that when I start my server I can view the files in a folder named 'my_directory' via the browser. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM httpd
COPY ./my_directory/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
COPY ./my-httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

I followed the documentation on Dockerhub and I also tried altering the directory settings in the httpd.conf file as so:

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted    
</Directory>
```

However every time I run my docker container and go to localhost:8080 I keep getting the default Apache html webpage 'It Works!'. What do I need to do so I can view the files in my directory instead?

Comment: have you just tried to specify a different volume for htdocs and conf directory when you create a container? that way you can adjust it all the same as if you are configuring a server outside of a container. Also, having indexes does not mean it will automatically show directory listing if for example you have mod_dir enabled and a index.html in your documentroot, in which case that file would be presented instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. Disabling mod_dir inside of the httpd.conf worked. I can now see my directory

Comment: @atlee19 - could you please share the steps with me.

Comment: @ezra-s could you please share the steps to configure directory listing.

Comment: Directory listing with "Options Indexes" is already enabled @SaravananJothilingam

Comment: @ezra-s  I have installed apache2 on SLES12 SP5 linux server. Here i need to know which are the conf files i need to edit inorder to make the directory listing via browser url. Can you share me the steps for this please. Appreciate this help.

Comment: In this question you can see an example of how to activate them, you just need the directory tag pointing to the directory where your files are and the "Options Indexes" directive and that's it. You can check about it at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options